# Symfony Solarium Data Import

Tags: php, symfony, solr, solarium

I am using Symfony NelmioSolariumBundle and need to make Solr full data import, has a Solarium such type of command?

If no, how to execute custom request for data import through Solarium API:

```
/core/dataimport?command=full-import
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the way to do it:

```
use Solarium\Core\Client\ClientInterface,
    Solarium\Core\Client\Request;

class IndexService
{
    /** @var ClientInterface */
    private $client;

    /**
     * @param ClientInterface $client
     */
    public function __construct(ClientInterface $client)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    public function triggerFullDataImport()
    {
        $request = new Request();
        $request->setHandler('dataimport');
        $request->addParam('command', 'full-import');

        $this->client->executeRequest($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any magic to do that, just call the URL with `file_get_contents("http://....")`. If fopen wrappers are disabled (they usually aren't), you can use the cURL module if its installed to do the same.

Comment: It seems like I asked a question in a very wrong way. I am using Symfony NelmioSolariumBundle and wanted to know how to do this throught API that this bundle provide